# Unable to deploy artifact from Appveyor to Github

Tags: github, appveyor

I am getting this message:

```
"GitHub" deployment has been skipped as environment variable has not matched ("appveyor_repo_tag" is "false", should be "true")
```

But, as can be seen in my Appveyor.yml:

https://github.com/GrokImageCompression/grok/blob/master/appveyor.yml

`appveyor_repo_tag` is actually set to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- remove [skip_tags: true](https://github.com/GrokImageCompression/grok/blob/master/appveyor.yml#L2)
- add `tag: $(APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG_NAME)` in GitHub deployment setting (to prevent AppVeyor from creating a new tag, and endless build loop)
- optionally add `force_update: true` (to update release details, not only files)

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "Github deployment setting"? I would like to use the tag that I pushed my changes to, no the one that Appveyor creates

Comment: `$(APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG_NAME)` is environment variable which exposes tag name you pushed (AppVeyor reads it from GitHub webhook). This will work for you.

Comment: deploy:
  tag: $(APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG_NAME)

Comment: is this what you mean ?